# System of equations and recurrence relation

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, systems-of-equations

I am trying to find the general solution for $N$ of the following system of equations

$$
\begin{cases}
    (x_n - x_{n-1})^2 + (y_n - y_{n-1})^2 = \left(\frac{\theta}{N}\right)^2 \\
    {x_n}^2 + {y_n}^2 = 1
\end{cases}
$$

with the initial values $x_0 = 1$ and $y_0 = 0$ and the following

- $\theta$ is a constant and $0 \leqslant \theta \leqslant 2$
- $N$ is a constant and we want to find the terms $(x_N, y_N)$

Using substitution with respect to $N$, we have

$$
\begin{align}
    x_0 = 1 \quad & ; \quad y_0 = 0 \\
    x_1 = -\frac{\theta^2 - 2N^2}{2N^2} \quad & ; \quad y_1 = -\frac{\theta \sqrt{4N^2 - \theta^2}}{2N^2} \\
    x_2 = \frac{\theta^4 - 4N^2\theta^2 + 2N^4}{2N^4} \quad & ; \quad y_2 = \frac{(\theta^3 - 2N^2\theta) \sqrt{4N^2 - \theta^2}}{2N^4} \\
    x_3 = -\frac{\theta^6 - 6N^2\theta^4 + 9N^4\theta^2 - 2N^6}{2N^6} \quad & ; \quad y_3 = -\frac{(\theta^5 - 4N^2\theta^3 + 3N^4\theta) \sqrt{4N^2 - \theta^2}}{2N^6}
\end{align}
$$

By using substitution, it becomes very difficult with $N \geqslant 2$.

Comment: Are you sure there is a closed form? Most nonlinear recurrences have no closed form

Comment: @HallaSurvivor yes of course, the closed form for $x_n$ is the power series for cosine! :-)

Comment: If you already know that, I'm afraid I'm not sure what your question is...

Comment: I am trying to derive the general method of solving such systems of equations. I know it is the power series for cosine because I extracted this system from the arc length formula applied to the unit circle. The only way I managed to solve this system was using substitution, followed by a guess and a possible proof using induction. However this is a tedious process and I wondered if it was possible using another method

Comment: I suspect there aren't any better methods - nonlinear recurrences are extremely chaotic in general. (+1) though, in the hopes someone more knowledgeable proves me wrong ^_^

Comment: It is a bad idea to write the equations in terms of the ratio $\frac\theta N$ instead of a single constant. This makes them very cumbersome.

Comment: @YvesDaoust would it be better to start without the ratio and add it later?

Comment: @eigenslacker: the ratio $\frac\theta N$ brings no added value. Both parameters are arbitrary and so is their ratio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using complex numbers as well, it is obvious from the second equation that the $n^{th}$ point can be written

$$z_n=e^{i\alpha_n}.$$

Then

$$|e^{i\alpha_n}-e^{i\alpha_{n-1}}|=|e^{i(\alpha_n-\alpha_{n-1})}-1|=|e^{i\alpha}-1|=\frac\theta N.$$

It is easy to show that this equation has at most two solutions in $e^{i\alpha}$, which are conjugate. If we always keep the same sign of $\alpha$, then by induction
$$z_n=e^{i\alpha_n}=e^{i\alpha_{n-1}}e^{i\alpha}=e^{in\alpha}.$$

Answer (score 1):

The second equation expresses that the points $(x_n,y_n)$ remain on the unit circle, and the first, that the successive points form chords of constant length, subtending an angle $\alpha=2\arcsin\frac\theta{2N}$.

Hence $$(x_n,y_n)=(\cos n\alpha,\sin n\alpha).$$

---

By the way, the system has in fact $2^n$ distinct solutions, as from every intermediate point, the chord can be drawn in two directions.

Comment: @eigenslacker: what more do you want for a proof ? This is elementary geometry.

Comment: Also, is it not rather $\alpha \leqslant 2 \arcsin\frac{\theta}{N}$ since the length of each chord is given by $0 \leqslant \theta \leqslant 2$?

Comment: @eigenslacker: no.

Comment: Can you explain how you found $\alpha = 2 \arcsin\frac{\theta}{N}$ please? I suspect you used the relation $\alpha = \pi - 2\arcsin\left(\frac{y_N}{\theta/N}\right)$ but I am not sure.

Comment: @eigenslacker: this is the chord-to-angle formula. But I just noticed that a factor $2$ was missing.